# Configure Django to allow login into Admin using Unix Users and Groups

Tags: python, django, unix

I am currently working on Django project where the users are created in database table. But, recently I have got the new requirement from management that they want to user Unix Users and Groups to login into Django Admin. I searched on google but didn't got any clues. Does anyone have any idea on same?

Regards,
Amit

Comment: I think this would be possible using LDAP - https://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/

Answer (score 0):

Normally linux systems use PAM for authentication, so have a look at https://github.com/tehmaze/django-pam. Another advantage of using PAM as API is, that systems configured for other authentication (ldap, nis, kerberos) should work as well.